# Variables in DB data to avoid redundancy?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

"Avoid redundancy" is important to me.

I want to store the input data for configuration management in a relational database.

My input data:

- project_name
- linux_user
- db_user
- db_name

In 95% of all cases all attributes are equal:

- project_name: foo
- linux_user: foo
- db_user: foo
- db_name: foo

If I would store this data in YAML, then I could use variables to avoid repetition.

AFAIK this does not work in relational databases.

I could store this in DB, but AFAIK I need to evaluate it myself:

- project_name: foo
- linux_user: {project_name}
- db_user: {project_name}
- db_name: {project_name}

How can I avoid redundancy if I store this in a relational database? Unfortunately these values are not always equal, only in most cases.

I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way of doing this in SQL. If the default is always the `project_name`, I would probably allow nulls in the other columns, and create a view that uses `coalesce()` to return a default value:

```
create view real_data
as
select project_name, 
       coalesce(linux_user, project_name) as linux_user,
       coalesce(db_user, project_name) as db_user,
       coalesce(db_name, project_name) as db_db_name
from base_data;
```

Another option would be a complicated case statement for each column:

```
create view real_data
as
select project_name, 
       case linux_user 
           when '{project_name}' then project_name
           when '{db_name}' then db_name
           when '{db_user}' then db_user
           else linux_user
       end as linux_user,
       ... repeat the above for the other columns ..
from base_data;
```

You could hide the `case` statement in a function or use a set returning function and dynamic SQL, so you don't need to hardcode each column name and possible variable.

If you only need to make sure you have a default value when creating the rows, then just replacing that in a trigger during insert might also be an option. That way there is no need for the view.

Comment: I like the `coalesce()` solution. I guess I will use this. Thank you for your answer.